# Can i set strings, singles etc to "" and Zero using for each?

Tags: vb6

I have a record:

```
Public Loon As LonenRecord

Type LonenRecord
    'Algemeen
    Status As String * 1
    TijdvakNr As Integer
    TijdvakBegin As String * 10
    TijdvakEinde As String * 10

    Key As String * 10
    WerkgeversNummer As String * 3
    WnRecord As Integer
    WerknemerNr As String * 4
    AchterNaam As String * 25
    Voorvoegsel As String * 15
    and lots more
end Type
```

I want so empty all to "" or zero

I can do:

```
with Loon
    .TijdvakNr  = 0
    .WerkgeversNummer  = ""
etc
end with
```

Is there a more simple way, f.i. with for each or whatever?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set a type in VBA to nothing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9788330/set-a-type-in-vba-to-nothing)

Answer (score 6):

Assign to a new value which will be in the default state.

```
'// return a new LonenRecord
Function ResetLonenRecord as LonenRecord: End Function
```

Then:

```
'// overwrite variable
Loon = ResetLonenRecord()
```

Comment: It looked a very good idea.
However, when running my program I get the error:
Compile error
Too many local, nonstatic variables
Do you have an idea to solve that?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Thats another issue, sounds like you need to refactor the procedure https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278420.aspx